# CSS grouping of several elements in a single id

Tags: php, mysql, css

In mysql database i have one text field called: gallery-27:

```
table{
    ..
    ..
}    
table tr td {
    ..
    ..
}    
table tr td img {
    ..
    ..
}       
table tr td:hover img {
    ..
    ..
}
```

in gallery.php i have:

```
<div id="gallery-27">
    <tr>
        <td><a .. ><img ...></a><td>
        <td><a .. ><img ...></a><td>
        ...
    </tr>
</div>
<div id="gallery-28">
    ...
</div>
```

is there a way to combine a id="gallery-27"  and code from the database in `<head>` or file.css like this?

```
#gallery-27{
    table{
        ..
        ..
    }    
    table tr td {
        ..
        ..
    }    
    table tr td img {
        ..
        ..
    }      
    table tr td:hover img {
        ..
        ..
    }
}
```

Don't work.. I no longer have ideas

Comment: just fetch the db values like you normally do then add it inside that tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i use this:

```
echo "<style>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        $id=$row['id'];
        $css=$row['css'];
        $css = str_replace( "}", "} #gallery-$id ", $css );
        $css = str_replace( "\n", "\r", $css );
        $css = str_replace( "\t", " ", $css );
        echo '#gallery-'.$id.' '.$css."{}\n";
    }
echo "</style>"
```